# VM can connect to SQL SERVER but not to ping the server

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ping, active-directory, sql-server

my schema is like this:

1. Windows Server 2016 with NAT adapter and Only Host Adapter using 192.168.3.2 255.255.255.0 acting as Active Directory Domain Service with DNS and DHCP enabled.

The DHCP is enabled to distribute addresses to other two Windows Server 2016 VM using 192.168.3.15 to 192.168.3.30

2. Windows Server 2016 acting as Domain User using 192.168.3.15 using AD Server also as DNS. It uses SQL SERVER
3. Windows Server 2016 acting as Domain User using 192.168.3.16 using AD Server also as DNS. It uses SQL SERVER

And i have tried to diagnose it like this:

Server 1 (AD) can ping Server 2, HOST, but not Server 3.

Server 2 can ping Server 1 (AD), Host, but no Server 3, but it can connect with SQL Server to Server 3. and see its database.

Server 3 can ping Server 1(AD), Server 2, Host

Host can ping Server 1 (AD), Server 2, but not server 3

All the servers are using NAT adapter as first adapter and the second adapter using ONLY HOST Network with no Virtual Box DHCP using 192.168.3.1 255.255.255.0

I'm trying to do SQL Server Mirroring but i think the main problem is that i can't ping Server 3 which has a SQL Server instance.

Comment: Verify your firewall settings first.  But, why are you using NAT and a local host adapter?  Multiple NICs on a domain controller isn't good practice. Set up a small linux router distro, like ipfire as your router, and have all your VMs go through that.  Only your router will have 2 nics (NAT and local), all the servers will be local only.

Comment: Thats because i watched a tutorial on that, and it worked, the AD worked with other VM and could ping. Until now that i find this problem on the third VM. I'm going to look into that router method.

Comment: I have a post on this on my blog: https://smudj.wordpress.com/2019/01/17/setting-up-an-all-in-one-windows-ad-test-environment-virtualbox-edition/ It should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Are you trying to ping/connect to SQL Server using IP or DNS?